# Why am I getting NaN instead of variable?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, for-loop, nan

Good morning,

I would like to ask you why am I getting Nan from this code? I have a Dataframe where are only 4 columns: flightID, timestamp, X and Y.

For each flight I have several rows with different timestamp and x,y positions. What I want is to calculate the time flown from each x,y coordinate. Then I want to compare the times flown from each x,y coordinates and have only the smallest ones for each x,y. I hope the code is written OK, but in the final min_time array I have a bunch of NaNs for x or y, can you please tell me why?

I have added a little code for creating dataframe similar to one I have so the example is reproducible.

```
data = {'flightID':['11111', '11111', '11111', '11111','2222','2222','2222','3333','3333','3333','3333'], 'timestamp':[1519669804, 1519669844,  1519669884, 1519669924,1519669976,1519679614,1519679615,1519679616,1519679800,1519679876,1519679999],'X':[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6],'Y':[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9]} 

Grid_frame2 = pd.DataFrame(data)




    # finding the cells which has something 
flight = []
min_time=[]

for j in range(len(Grid_frame2)-1):
    if Grid_frame2.flightID[j] == Grid_frame2.flightID[j+1]:        # find all the rows from the same flight
        arr = [Grid_frame2.timestamp[j]]
        arr.append(Grid_frame2.X[j])
        arr.append(Grid_frame2.Y[j])
        flight = np.reshape(flight,(-1,3))
        flight = np.vstack((flight,arr))
        arr = []
    else:                                                         # if you have the last one, compute time flown
        time = flight[-1][0] - flight[0][0]
        time = abs(time)
        x = flight[0][1]
        y = flight[0][2]
        if len(min_time) == 0:                                    # if min_time array is empty, insert values
            arr = [time]
            arr.append(x)
            arr.append(y)
            min_time.append(arr)
            arr = []
            flight = []
        else:                                                     # is it is not empty, check if there is the same cell and if it is not smaller value
            for k in range(len(min_time)):
                if min_time[k][1] == x and min_time[k][2] == y and min_time[k][0] > int(time):
                    min_time[k][0] = time
                    flight= []
                elif min_time[k][1] == x and min_time[k][2] == y and min_time[k][0] < int(time):
                    flight = []
                    pass
                else:                                             # if there is no same cell or the value isn't higher, insert values
                    arr = [time]
                    arr.append(x)
                    arr.append(y)
                    min_time = np.vstack((min_time,arr))
                    #min_time = np.reshape(min_time,(-1,3))
                    arr = []
                    flight = []
```

The problem is that if I try to see what is after this loop in min_time array, it looks like this:

```
> array([[691.,   1.,   7.],
       [812.,  nan,   7.],
       [898.,   6.,  nan],
       ...,
       [769.,  nan,   9.],
       [769.,  nan,   9.],
       [769.,  nan,   9.]])
```

Also, the length should be 150, since I have a grid with the x,y coordinates which is (10x15) and the length is actually more than 1000

Comment: Hi Lucie. You're using Pandas, which is great, but take note that iterating over a pandas dataframe should be your absolutely last option. They're designed so that you can carry out a whole host of functions without needing to loop over them. That said, I've just run your code, and don't get the same output for min_time; I get this: `array([[8.000e+01, 1.000e+00, 7.000e+00],
       [9.638e+03, 2.000e+00, 7.000e+00]])`

Comment: You should try to edit your question with a clearer description of what you're trying to do, including an example of what your output should look like, which will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I am a total beginner, I started coding two weeks ago. I wanted to work with that things in Pandas but this was easier to implement for me. Actually, I figured it out, I have had a problem in the original Dataframe I am using. The only thing now is that it adds a new row with the same x,y to the min_time even if it is already in there

Answer (score 1):

I read your code and noticed a problem here:

```
if min_time[k][1] == x and min_time[k][2] == y and min_time[k][0] > int(time):
    ...
elif min_time[k][1] == x and min_time[k][2] == y and min_time[k][0] < int(time):
    ...
```

What if `min_time[k][0] == int(time)`? That extra row may comes from here.

However, even after adjusting here, the code behaves strangely (I'm not sure what you want to do and more information is needed)

---

I hope I understand your code and what are you doing here, below are some suggestions or hints.

1. Make your code more elegant and readable.

   ```
   # Yes
   min_time.append([time,x,y])

   # No
   arr = [time]
   arr.append(x)
   arr.append(y)
   min_time.append(arr)
   arr = []
   ```

   ```
   # Yes
   flight.append(Grid_frame2.loc[j,['timestamp','X','Y']])

   # No
   arr = [Grid_frame2.timestamp[j]]
   arr.append(Grid_frame2.X[j])
   arr.append(Grid_frame2.Y[j])
   flight = np.reshape(flight,(-1,3))
   flight = np.vstack((flight,arr))
   arr = []
   ```
2. You will find the charm and magic of `pandas` after running this (I guess you may want to do this):

   ```
   def get_flight_info(x):
       time = x['timestamp'].iloc[-1]-x['timestamp'].iloc[0]
       location = x[['X','Y']].iloc[0]
       return location.append(pd.Series([time],index=['min_time']))

   flight_info = Grid_frame2.groupby(['flightID']).apply(get_flight_info)
   min_time_in_location = flight_info.groupby(['X','Y'])['min_time'].min()
   ```